# Display a date with morris

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I try to display dates with  morris chart. The date format is "2016-05-18T16:00:00Z". 
I try to display my data as a morris bar chart. I write a function in nodejs that return my data as :
[{date: "2017-07-28T00:00:00Z", energiep1: 3, energiep2: 0}......}] . After that i write this code:

```
 Morris.Bar({
 element: 'bar-example',
 data: <%=datas %>,
 xkey: 'date',
 ykeys: ['energiep1'],
 labels: ['Energie'],
 pointSize: 2,
 hideHover: 'auto',
 resize: true,
```

But with this date format i can't display my chart. I tried to use Date.parse and it worked .But the format is integer (example:15412000001) not a date.

Do anyone have an idea if it's possible or not?
Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok i did it.Can you please check the edit. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Unfortunately, I'm no `morris.js` expert so I can't provide an answer. I was just reviewing your question...